# Path output differs in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, svg

I have a path which i have mentioned in the below code snippet. If i run this in chrome and other browsers, the output of chrome browser differs from other browsers.

```
<svg id="container" style="width: 800px; height: 400px;">
<path id="container_svg" fill="#E94649" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke="transparent" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M 0 198.33333333333334 L 0 198.33333333333334 C 33.14285714284961 198.09968472079086 66.28571428569921 197.8660361082484 99.42857142857142 198.33333333333334 C 132.57142857142102 198.80063055841828 165.71428571427063 199.9688736211306 198.85714285714283 198.33333333333334 C 231.99999999999244 196.6977930455361 265.14285714284205 192.25846940722928 298.2857142857143 198.33333333333334 C 331.4285714285639 204.4081972594374 364.57142857141355 220.99724874995226 397.71428571428567 198.33333333333334 C 430.8571428571353 175.66941791671437 463.9999999999849 113.75253559296158 497.14285714285717 90.83666666666667 C 530.2857142857067 67.92079774037181 563.4285714285563 84.00594221153479 596.5714285714286 83.3 C 629.7142857142782 82.59405778846521 662.8571428571278 65.09702889423264 696 47.600000000000016 L 696 198.33333333333334 ">
</path>
```

Output of chrome browser:
[image: Chrome]

Output of firefox browser:
[image: Firefox]

Output of IE:
[image: IE]

Kindly, suggest me a way to overcome this issue.

Thanks in advance,
Dharanidharan.

Comment: I'm assuming you would like the chrome output yes?

Comment: No, i need the output as in firefox browser.

Comment: Raise a chrome bug on its bugtracker.

Comment: Interesting bug. It doesn't happen every time.